# Getting test tree from all Cucumber features and scenarios?

Tags: java, cucumber

Am I wondering if there is a possibility to build a cucumber test tree that will include feature/'List of scenario names' partition? 
Can't find any commands in cucumber utilities.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Java as it tagged